# List append in loop question

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i modify this code to make 3 lists with 5 elements in each instead of as it is now; 3 lists with 5/10/15 elements?

```
import random

y = []

def autoSolve():
    for i in range(5):
        z = random.randrange(1, 10)
        y.append(z)
    print(y, end="")

for i in range(3):
    print("number", i + 1,)
    autoSolve()
    print()
```

Comment: why do you think you have three lists?  Because print is called three times?

Comment: Note that the generation of the list in autoSolve could be more compactly written like this: `y = [random.randrange(1,10) for _ in range(5)]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move `y = []` into the autoSolve method, so that it's reset on every call.

```
def autoSolve():
    y = []
    for i in range(5):
        z = random.randrange(1, 10)
        y.append(z)
    print(y, end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the same list `y` each time.

`y` starts off empty.

The first iteration of your for loop, `y` ends up with 5 elements.

The second iteration, `y.append` causes it to increase to 10 elements.

To prevent this, put the line

```
y=[]
```

inside the `autoSolve()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `y = []` to the beginning of `autoSolve`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

y = []

def autoSolve():
    x = []
    for i in range(5):
        z = random.randrange(1, 10)
        x.append(z)
    print(x, end="")
    return x

for i in range(3):
    print("number", i + 1,)
    y.append(autoSolve())
    print()
```

Comment: This is quite a confusing answer for him if he doesn't understand global variables in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def autoSolve():
    y = []
    for i in range(5):
        z = random.randrange(1, 10)
        y.append(z)
    return y #you could return instead, it'd be cleaner 
   
for i in range(3):
    print("number", i + 1,)
    print(autoSolve())
```

```
number 1
[4, 8, 4, 2, 9]
number 2
[8, 2, 4, 8, 9]
number 3
[4, 8, 1, 3, 5]

[Program finished]
```

Alternate way using list comprehension,

```
import random

lists = [[random.randrange(1, 10) for i in range(5)] for j in range(3)]

for lst in lists:
  print(f"Number: {lists.index(lst)+1}")
  print(f"List: {lst}")
  print("")
```

Using `random.choices`

```
import random

lists = [random.choices(range(10), k = 5)for j in range (3 )]
    

for i, lst in enumerate(lists, start=1):
  print(f"Number: {i}")
  print(f"List: {lst}")
  print("")
```

```
Number: 1
List: [0, 8, 4, 5, 0]

Number: 2
List: [3, 4, 6, 2, 1]

Number: 3
List: [9, 6, 5, 9, 9]


[Program finished]
```

Answer (score -1):

i think this would be suitable solution for this problem.

```
import random

y = []

def autoSolve():
    x = []
    for i in range(5):
        z = random.randrange(1, 10)
        x.append(z)
    y.append(x)
    print(y, end="")

 for i in range(3):
    print("number", i + 1,)
    autoSolve()
    print()
```

here output will generate as this [ [ ], [ ], [ ] ] formate
A list with 3 inner list of 5 element